# Change color of matching string characters in for loop php

Tags: php

I have this loop:

```
for ($m=0; $m<7; $m++){
if ($myextra[$m] == $drawextra[$m]) {
$myextra[$m] = '<span class="matchx">'.$myextra[$m].'</span>';
}
}
echo $myextra;
```

My echo output is as follows:

```
 3445<<8
<11<<6<
<45<<<<
```

The class in the  is from my stylesheet and should color the matched character in the string but the matched character is simply replaced by '<'. They are in the correct position but how can I assign that class properly?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you provide example value for $myextra and $drawextra? Also an example expected output?

Comment: I think he wants to search for one word in the whole passage, and then add tags around it. Am i correct frank?

Comment: i dont know what do you want but try `style="color:red;"` instead of `class="matchx"

Comment: $myextra and $drawextra are both strings with 7 characters each. In my case the characters are  numbers so basically I have a 7 digit number as a string. I compare the numbers in each string for exact match and position. Output should show my string with matches a different color.

Comment: Thanks to all. Several of your solutions worked but I could only accept 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use [] notation to change more than one char in string.
You have to use new variable:

```
$result = '';
for ($m=0; $m<7; $m++){
    if ($myextra[$m] == $drawextra[$m]) {
        $result .= '<span class="matchx">'. $myextra[$m] .'</span>';
    } else {
        $result .= $myextra[$m];
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a temporary variable ie:

```
$rez = "";
for ($m=0; $m<7; $m++){
  if ($myextra[$m] == $drawextra[$m]) {
    $rez .= '<span class="matchx">'.$myextra[$m].'</span>';
  }else{
    $rez .=$myextra[$m];
  }
}
$myextra = $rez;
unset($rez);

echo $myextra;
```

Comment: This returns my strings but not showing any different color for matched characters.

Comment: I try this  
`<?php  
$myextra = '1634567';  
$drawextra = '7654321';  

$rez = "";  
for ($m=0; $m<7; $m++){  
  if ($myextra[$m] == $drawextra[$m]) {  
    $rez .= '<span class="matchx">'.$myextra[$m].'</span>';  
  }else{  
    $rez .=$myextra[$m];  
  }  
}  
$myextra = $rez;  
unset($rez);  

echo $myextra;   
`  output is : 1<span class="matchx">6</span>3<span class="matchx">4</span>567

Comment: Is matchx class defined correctly ?  You can use `style="color:red;"` (advise by cryptic)